# Linear Bound Automaton Power

Tags: proof-techniques

Please tell me is their deterministic linear bound automaton same power as non-deterministic linear bound automaton to recognize any language?

Comment: Your question is already answered on [Wikipedia's page on linear bounded automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_bounded_automaton): see, in particular, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_bounded_automaton#LBA_problems.  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking, and to search standard references (e.g., Wikipedia, textbooks) before asking here.  If your question is answered in the obvious place on Wikipedia, you probably should do more research before asking in the future. There's little point in us duplicating material already available in standard resources.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is equivalent to asking whether or not $DSPACE(O(n)) = NSPACE(O(n))$, which is an open problem, known as the first LBA problem.